# Bootstrap (2.3.2) dropdown not playing nicely with wrapping div with overflow-x set

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a bunch of tables with many columns. The tables need to be individually scrollable. The first column of each  contains a bootstrap 2.3.2 button group that includes a dropdown menu.

Simplified example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w4s24Lgy/2/

```
<div style="overflow-x: scroll">
    <table style="width: 2000px">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td style="width: 120px">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Action b</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Action iii</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Yet Another Action</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>                  
              </td>
              <td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td style="width: 120px">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Action b</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Action iii</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Yet Another Action</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>                  
              </td>
              <td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td style="width: 120px">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Action b</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Action iii</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Yet Another Action</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>                  
              </td>
              <td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td style="width: 120px">
                  <div class="btn-group">
                      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                      <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action 1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Action b</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Action iii</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Yet Another Action</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>                  
              </td>
              <td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td><td style="width: 300px">td content blah, blah, blah</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div>Some not very wide other stuff</div>
</div>
```

When the dropdown is triggered on lower rows it gets cut off (effectively, actually moved into a scrollable y overflow area).

I know that this happens in certain browsers because an overflow of visible in one dimension won't play nicely with anything other than visible in the other dimension, but have no idea how to fix it.

How can either or both of the scrolling or dropdown be changed to play well together?